# Validate pre-existing mogodb collection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to run mongoose schema validation on pre-existing collections.  The collections were created with mongoose so the documents are generally correct, but if the schema changes in some way, fields added/removed, types changed, etc. I have to write a script to make those changes manually to the collection.

I decided that a more flexible/reusable solution would be to just run the schema validation over the whole collection.  However, that doesn't seem to be as easy as I thought it would be.

My problem is that currently, the only time the validation gets run is on document creation and an update using the `save()` method.  Save injects `$set` so it doesn't overwrite the document, and only validates fields that are being written.  So, for example, if field `foo` got changed from a string to a number with default 0, any documents with strings already in `foo` need to be found and set to default.

I am currently retrieving all docs, iterating over each one and calling `.save()`, if there is a type error, I delete the offending field using `err.path` and try to save again, repeating util there are no errors.  I thought for sure that would set any field that doesn't match the schema to its default, but `save()` doesn't overwrite the doc, so if a field exists in the db but not in the doc being saved it leaves it alone and nothing happens.

There is an overwrite option on mongooses update method, but update doesn't run validation so I'm stuck.

Comment: Since you're already retrieving all of them, you could just remove the collection and then run `.create()`.

Comment: @cdbajorin I create and save throw errors if the validation fails... that wouldn't set any pre-existing fields to default.

Comment: Maybe I'm not fully understanding what you're attempting to do. You're talking about pre-existing fields in the database and saving default values. If you delete all the documents from the database after `.find()`, you can just turn them all into objects and call `.create()`. Nothing will exist in the database, so there is nothing to overwrite.